# Strange C#.Net dependency between local dll and nuget lib

Tags: c#, jenkins, nuget

I have a project for a .Net log component.

As I use this in many other projects I decided in the past to push it on nuget.org. In other projects I do reference this package.

So far so good.

Now I started to setup a deployment server using Jenkins.

In Jenkins I have a project that builds this log component and copy the artifact log.dll to a final destination.

When the component that works fine with the log.dll from nuget.org package uses the local build log.dll from the Jenkins build.

I get this error in event-log:

```
Application: ServiceConsole.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: 
The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: 
System.IO.FileLoadException at ServiceConsole.MainForm..ctor() 
at ServiceConsole.Program.Main()
```

And another

```
ServiceConsole.exe 
   2.10.0.0 
   5b3f4a6d 
   KERNELBASE.dll 
   10.0.14393.2312 
   5b1a1651 
   e0434352 
   0000000000033c58 
   480c 
   01d4153f46b746a1 
   C:\bin\ServiceConsole.exe 
   C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll 
   05d03123-c336-4119-947f-7de71a75c0b5
```

I did compare the two dll (from nuget.org and locally build with jenkins (msbuild.exe)).

Both dll have:

- equal code
- have equal size
- compiled release
- build same assembly version
- same product version

*The only difference that just came into my mind is that msbuild.exe in Jenkins is from VS2017 build tools while months ago I did publish the dll on nuget was VS2015.*

Anyone have a clue what this could be? Really a compiler issue?

**Edit** Was curious and installed MSBuild.exe from VS2015 (Version 14) and changed Jenkins settings. The locally build with this build did not work either...

So the only difference I think I still have is that the former package I pushed on nuget.org was build on my develop machine using VS2015 IDE.

**Edit**

Start code that is not even fired:

```
static class Program
    {
        private static readonly string _assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      try
      {
        Console.WriteLine("starting app");
        using (var processLock = new ProcessLock(_assemblyName))
        {
          if (processLock.AlreadyExists)
            return;

          // The program operation must run inside the 'using' block.
          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
      }


    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

So it seems to turn out that changing the signed key file after last push to nuget the public key token changes and results into this error.

```
start appSystem.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Log, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8a1542bdbac62407' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Common.Log, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8a1542bdbac62407'
   at ServiceConsole.MainForm..ctor()
   at ServiceConsole.Program.Main()

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Common.Log, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8a1542bdbac62407
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/prog/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : ServiceConsole, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Common.Log, Version=2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8a1542bdbac62407
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/prog/bin/Common.Log.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Looking for confirmation.
So next step to fix that is publish new version to nuget and use it, but have to raise the version number. Correct?

Comment: It would be really useful to know the full exception message and stack trace from the crashing exception rather than only its type. Can you provide some logs or related info too?

Comment: Have no stacktrace in event log and my program do not throw an exception, no clue why. I still try to find on what is going on...

Comment: I tried get this problem reproduced from VS IDE, but starting the project in Debug from VS IDE 2017 I do not get any error...

Comment: No other clue leaves guessing as the only chance of finding the error. At the very least, try adding an error handling in `Main` that just writes the `Exception.ToString()` to a file and rethrows, that would give the message in a plain text file, and is just a few lines to change.

Comment: I did add this, but not even fired. So the IOLoadException probably is not in my code, it is while loading the dll reference...

Comment: .Net knows where DLLs came from and has different security policies based on their origin. Even when the files are identical they could have different security restrictions applied depending where you copied them from

Comment: @bikeman868 And how do I find out if that is the problem? And how to solve it? In this case I can not use nuget.org?!

Comment: Your `catch` block is writing to the console, but you're in a Winforms program, that output won't be shown anywhere. Use a text file instead, that you can look at after the fact. The dll is loaded, by default, upon its first use, very likely within your code, so this should trigger the catch block, but my guess is that the console write has no effect.

Comment: You can use Nuget of course, I use it all the time and am also the author of many Nuget packages. You could only get into problems if you were trying to use it in some non-standard way. If there is a security issue with a DLL you will get an assembly load exception thrown within your application. If there is a security issue with the application EXE file itself then Windows will tell you that when you try to launch the application.

Comment: What is the account that runs Jenkins? If you don't specifically set the service to run UI code it won't run it. Perhaps it's better to put the logic of your program in a console application and use it in Jenkins instead, and save the UI for human interaction.

Comment: On the road atm, need to check. I guess it is something about security as everything else works fine. I will follow advice write alog when back to desk and update here then

Comment: Hello, I checked repository history, and one thing I just saw is that the assembly was signed with a pfx file (password protected) and now it is not anymore. Now we have a snk file file (without password). So this can cause the error?

Comment: If you don’t sign the assembly correctly then it will not load. This is to protect you from executing code that is not from a trusted source.

Comment: It turns out that the pfx was replaced by a snk file and this difference causes all my troubles. @bikeman868 If you add your comments as answer I can upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the assemblies are identical in a binary compare and one loads but the other does not it is likely to be a security issue.

.Net tracks the origin of assemblies and applies different security policies for assemblies that originated from the Internet for example to protect you from accidentally running malicious code.

Two identical assemblies could be treated differently by the .Net loader if they were copied from different places.